# Push Messaging Distribution Device Token

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I am using EasyAPNS for Push Messaging and I kept getting the following error when switch a device to Production:

**APNS responded with error for pid(201). status(8: Invalid token)**

As I understand you have separate device tokens for sandbox and production, but it is only registering the sandbox device token. I have set up both development and distribution provisioning profiles and set them correctly in both the target and the project setting.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or shed some light on this matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Accept some answers Hassan :) people will be more happy to help you. :)

Comment: are you testing with Device... Because  simulator can not log device token

Comment: I am testing with device and not simulator

Comment: have u changed the Sandbox url "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com" to Production url "gateway.push.apple.com" ?

Comment: Have you done all the necessary certificate stuff i.e. enabling APNS on a deployment provisioning profile?

Comment: I have changed the URL and enabled APNS on the deployment provisioning profile